# Probability that a random integer matrix is singular

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$-matrix with integers in the range $u..v$ , where $u<v$ are arbitary 
 integers. Is there a formula, or at least, a good estimate, for the probability
 that the matrix is singular? In the case $u=v$, the answer is obviously $1$.

It is intuitively clear, that the probability very quickly tends to $0$, if the range
 increases. As I tried, the probability that a $4\times4$-matrix with integers from $-100..100$
 is singular is very small indeed. Of course, brute force is hopeless, a simulation
 would give crude approximations. I prefer suitable bounds.

Comment: Of course, $n>1$ is assumed.

Comment: I would try to solve this problem in a recurrent way. Say you generate the first row and estimate the number of rows proportional to this row and in your range. Compare with the number of possible second rows. On the second step you have 2 independent rows and estimate the number of linear combination of these rows versus the same number of possible rows. Etc.

Comment: A nice approach! I will think about it.